# WixToolkit in Visual Studio building MSI into folder named "unused"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix

I have a WIX project in Visual Studio 2015 via the WIX Toolkit.  A small issue I'm getting is the .MSI file is being generated into a folder named "unused" but I have no idea why.  Where is it getting this path from?

I can see the command to light.exe which has the correct path specified in the "out" parameter with the exception of it adding a folder named "unused" to it. For example,

Light.exe -out "C:\code\someapp\bin\release\unused\someapp.msi"

My build configuration xml in the project file is,

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <SuppressSpecificWarnings>1076</SuppressSpecificWarnings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

If I change "OutputPath" to "bin\$(Configuration)\test", it builds everything inside of a folder named test, but also dumps the MSI file into a folder named "unused" inside of that.

Any ideas?

Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a .wxl file with `Culture="unused"`.

Comment: Great thanks, I tried removing it but the installer complained so I'm going to opt for a post build script to move my output files.  Cheers.